# First time for an event and last time before

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

I  am observing if an event (MG) has happened or not on a material at a point in time. The duration between each observation varies from 1 to 3 or more weeks.  Now I want to find the first week the event happened and the last week before.

```
df <- data.frame(Weeks=c(1,2,3,5,1,2,7,10), Material=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)), MG=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1))
```

this is how I want the outcome to be

```
outputwanted <- data.frame(Material=c("A","B"), firstweek=c(5,7), lastbefore=c(3,2))
```

I have tried "slice" to find the first time it happens, but can I use it also for my other purpose?

```
df %>% group_by(Material) %>% slice(which.max(MG))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `which.max` in `summarise` and to calculate `lastbefore` we can subtract 1 from `firstweek` for each `Material`. This is assuming that there would always be at least 1 one in each group i.e `Material`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  summarise(firstweek = Weeks[which.max(MG)], 
            lastbefore = Weeks[which.max(MG) - 1])


#  Material firstweek lastbefore
#  <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 A                5          3
#2 B                7          2
```

If there could be groups without 1's in it we can use either `match`

```
df %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  summarise(firstweek = Weeks[match(1, MG)], 
            lastbefore = Weeks[match(1, MG) - 1])
```

Or `which` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  summarise(firstweek = Weeks[which(MG == 1)[1]], 
            lastbefore = Weeks[which(MG ==1)[1] - 1])
```

Comment: This solution is helpful, thanks! However, the intervals between observing times are not equal; sometimes it is one week, other times, it can sometimes be two or three weeks between observations. Then this solution does not work. I should, of course, have given this information in the question..

Comment: @user4631839 Sorry, do you mean you want t0 get corresponding `Week` value of first  `MG` ? like `df %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  summarise(firstweek = Weeks[which.max(MG)], 
            lastbefore = firstweek - 1)` ?

Comment: I realise that I had to rephrase my original question. I changed the example also and hope this will bring more clarity to my question. Sorry!

Comment: I still don't get it. The first row values of 5 and 3 I understand that it 5 is because it is the first week when `MG == 1` and 3 is the week before. I don't understand 7 and 2 though for "B".

Comment: Oh no, I added the wrong df. Changed it again. Now I hope it is clear. Sorry for all this inconvenience.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you it worked fine. However, in my data, there are some cases where the event doesn't happen during the entire study. Then this doesn´t work. I have tried to figure out how to not include them in the evaluation but I really cannot figure out how. `df3 <- data.frame(Weeks=c(1,2,3,5,1,2,7,10),
                 Material=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)), 
                 MG=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))`   `df3 %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  summarise(firstweek = Weeks[which.max(MG)], 
            lastbefore = Weeks[which.max(MG) - 1])`

Comment: @user4631839 What output do you want when no event happens? If you use `match` option it returns `NA`.

Comment: Added another option to use `which`, which also returns `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, {i1 <- which.max(MG)
           .(firstweek = Week[i1],
              lastbefore = Week[i1-1])} , Material]
```